# I got this error "provide a valid google app engine location" and I can't use GAE in my project

Tags: netbeans

[NetBeans] I got this error "provide a valid google app engine location" and I can't use GAE in my project.
I select the correct path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine
and still getting that error. how to fix it?

Comment: Shot in the dark: try installing GAE in c:\gae ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you must select the location you unzipped the Google App Engine SDK.

Comment: I think that was the thing I've done. I cannot say if it work or not because I'm not using GAE anymore. I will accept it anyway

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work with newer version of Google App Engine. It works with this one here:
https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/appengine-sdks/o/featured%2Fappengine-java-sdk-1.9.76.zip?generation=1561410304446824&alt=media

Comment: Please don't post links only.

Comment: @RussJ. It is a link that allows people to download the zip file directly. No further explaination is needed given the answer is provided above.

Comment: Then please move your answer to comment on the answer above.

Comment: It says I have to have 50+ pts to make a comment. Sorry